# Why does Selection.selectAllChildren() select shadow DOM custom element in Chrome but not Firefox?

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom

I'm curious about some differing behavior between browsers in response to using javascript's [`Selection.selectAllChildren()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/selectAllChildren) from the shadow DOM, and I'd like to achieve a consistent result somehow (whether using the shadow DOM or some other method).

(Browsers tested: Chrome 106.0.5249.119, Firefox 105.0.3, and Safari 16.0)

I'm creating a bookmarklet that injects HTML to allow the user to select DOM tree nodes. For the purposes of this question, the test case is this: A button appended to `document.body` selects all children of `document.body` with `Selection.selectAllChildren()`. My aim is to *exclude* the button text from the selection.

(*Note: I'm using `document.body` as the target in this test case because the bookmarklet needs to be able to traverse the DOM up to and including `<body>`—while, hopefully, at the same time, excluding its own injected HTML from the selection.*)

### Without shadow DOM:

```js
let sel = window.getSelection();
let target = document.body;
let aBtn = document.querySelector("#select") 
aBtn.onclick = (e) => {
      sel.selectAllChildren(target);
    }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div>
Sint magna duis incididunt, sunt laborum esse.Dolor veniam fugiat amet exercitation, ut ad. Amet exercitation ut ad nisi ex cupidatat nulla. Ut, ad nisi ex cupidatat nulla dolore incididunt.
</div>
<div>
Laborum esse non qui ut culpa. Non qui ut culpa. Ut culpa quis, eu et labore exercitation.
</div>
<div>
Dolore, non ullamco ullamco proident. Ullamco proident incididunt excepteur consequat pariatur eiusmod anim.</div>
<button id="select">
Select
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

When the button is clicked, on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, the button text is included in the selection. Although my goal is to exclude the button text, all three browsers behave the same way.

### With shadow DOM

If instead I inject the button using a shadow dom custom element (note: I'm *very* unfamiliar with the shadow dom), the button text is *excluded* from the selection on Firefox and Safari:

[image: Button text is excluded in Firefox/Safari]

but the button text is *included* in Chrome:

[image: Button text is included in Chrome]

Example:

```js
let sel = window.getSelection();
let target = document.body;

class shadowBtn extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({
      mode: "open"
    });

    const aBtn = document.createElement("button");
    aBtn.innerHTML = "Select";
    shadow.appendChild(aBtn);

    aBtn.onclick = (e) => {
     sel.selectAllChildren(target);
    }

  }
}
customElements.define("shadow-button", shadowBtn);
let buttonInstance = document.createElement("shadow-button")
document.body.appendChild(buttonInstance)
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div>
Sint magna duis incididunt, sunt laborum esse.Dolor veniam fugiat amet exercitation, ut ad. Amet exercitation ut ad nisi ex cupidatat nulla. Ut, ad nisi ex cupidatat nulla dolore incididunt.
</div>
<div>
Laborum esse non qui ut culpa. Non qui ut culpa. Ut culpa quis, eu et labore exercitation.
</div>
<div>
Dolore, non ullamco ullamco proident. Ullamco proident incididunt excepteur consequat pariatur eiusmod anim.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have two questions:

1. Which is the correct browser behavior?
2. How can I achieve the result where the button text is excluded from the selection in all modern browsers?

Comment: Post 1. where the developers are: https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues

Answer (score 1):

So:

1 - Which is the correct browser behavior?

There is no correct browser behavior but users are mostly using Chrome, so if we are choosing between what is the correct way, it will be Chrome.

2- I am not sure whether it can be helpful for you or not, but in your code, you are defining target as the "body" of the HTML. So, if you are selecting that, it will include the button too (cause it is part of the body). you can use the following code to exclude button (to include just "div" section of your code to be selected after clicking on the button:

HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="this">
Sint magna duis incididunt, sunt laborum esse.Dolor veniam fugiat amet exercitation, ut ad. Amet exercitation ut ad nisi ex cupidatat nulla. Ut, ad nisi ex cupidatat nulla dolore incididunt.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS Code:

```
let sel = window.getSelection();
let target = document.getElementById("this");

class shadowBtn extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({
      mode: "open"
    });

    const aBtn = document.createElement("button");
    aBtn.innerHTML = "Select";
    shadow.appendChild(aBtn);

    aBtn.onclick = (e) => {
      sel.selectAllChildren(target);
    }

  }
}
customElements.define("shadow-button", shadowBtn);
let buttonInstance = document.createElement("shadow-button")
document.body.appendChild(buttonInstance)
```

Comment: Thank you, @amirhossein-sefati. Re 1) That's surprising to me, since it seems I frequently run across examples of browsers adhering to or deviating from standards. 2) You're right, specifying a target element that doesn't include the button would work, however I need to (if possible) exclude the button while targeting `<body>`. (This is why I supposed that the shadow DOM might be helpful.) I've added a note to clarify this in my question.

Answer (score 0):

> 2. How can I achieve the result where the button text is excluded from the selection in all modern browsers?

I've found one answer to the second part of my question. If I can make certain that the injected HTML (the button, in the test case) is the last child of `<body>`, I can use [`Selection.setBaseAndExtent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/setBaseAndExtent) to select everything except the button:

`sel.setBaseAndExtent(document.body.firstChild, 0, aBtn, 0);`

Example:

```js
let sel = window.getSelection();
let target = document.body;
let aBtn = document.querySelector("#select") 
aBtn.onclick = (e) => {
     // sel.selectAllChildren(target);
     sel.setBaseAndExtent(document.body.firstChild, 0, aBtn, 0);
    }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div>
Sint magna duis incididunt, sunt laborum esse.Dolor veniam fugiat amet exercitation, ut ad. Amet exercitation ut ad nisi ex cupidatat nulla. Ut, ad nisi ex cupidatat nulla dolore incididunt.
</div>
<div>
Laborum esse non qui ut culpa. Non qui ut culpa. Ut culpa quis, eu et labore exercitation.
</div>
<div>
Dolore, non ullamco ullamco proident. Ullamco proident incididunt excepteur consequat pariatur eiusmod anim.</div>
<button id="select">
Select
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: using `document.body.firstChild` will cause to just select the first child in your body which is that `<div>` above the `button`. It is not different than my answer I think!

Comment: Actually @amirhossein-sefati, `document.body.firstChild` becomes the `anchorNode` parameter of `Selection.setBaseAndExtent(anchorNode, anchorOffset, focusNode, focusOffset)`. As the `anchorNode`, it forms the start of the selection, and the `focusNode` (the button) terminates the selection. I've updated the example to show how the new code selects all children of `<body>` except the last one, `<button>`.